# Recreation of ChromaDB Embeddings: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite, langchain, chromadb

I am working on the RAG application which provides Custom GPT Bot service, I am storing the file URLs that GPT is using to answer the user query.

[image]

I am storing the Embedding against each bot_id separately. Following are the embeddings for each bot stored separately which are retreived based on the bot_id in use.

[image]

When the user changes the File URLs I delete the existing ChromaDB folder for that bot and recreate embeddings on a new file URL and it shows the following error while recreating embeddings:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 438, in _validate_tenant_database
    self._admin_client.get_tenant(name=tenant)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 486, in get_tenant
    return self._server.get_tenant(name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/segment.py", line 140, in get_tenant
    return self._sysdb.get_tenant(name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/mixins/sysdb.py", line 125, in get_tenant
    with self.tx() as cur:
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite.py", line 131, in tx
    return TxWrapper(self._conn_pool, stack=self._tx_stack)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._conn = conn_pool.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite_pool.py", line 141, in connect
    new_connection = Connection(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite_pool.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._conn = sqlite3.connect(
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/ubuntu/chatbot/main.py", line 460, in qa
    message = storeEmbeddings(embedding_model, raw_text, bot_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/chatbot/embeddings.py", line 12, in storeEmbeddings
    db = Chroma.from_documents(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 778, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 714, in from_texts
    chroma_collection = cls(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 120, in __init__
    self._client = chromadb.Client(_client_settings)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 274, in Client
    return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._validate_tenant_database(tenant=tenant, database=database)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/client.py", line 447, in _validate_tenant_database
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not connect to tenant default_tenant. Are you sure it exists?
```

Seems like it's still trying to access the old ChromaDB for that bot even though the folder was deleted successfully. I have deleted by folder using:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("Embeddings/1001")
```

Function that creates and store embeddings:

```
def storeEmbeddings(embedding, text, bot_id, embedding_folder):

    try:

        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)

        texts = text_splitter.create_documents([text])

        db = Chroma.from_documents(
            texts,
            embedding,
            persist_directory=embedding_folder+"//"+bot_id,
            client_settings=Settings(anonymized_telemetry=False,is_persistent=True,),
        )

        return sucessMessage
    
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

And the most strange thing is that, when I stop-and-start the python app at this point, it recreate the embeddings for this bot.

What's the best way to delete existing ChromaDB embeddings and create for new documents?